# How do you make a human-readable date? "7 minutes ago" in Swift 3?

Tags: swift, swift3, date-formatting

I'm trying to format a label to say "_ minutes ago". How would I go about it?

I have it formatted right now to just say, for example, "11:45 PM".

```
let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
dateFormatter.calendar = Calendar.current
dateFormatter.timeStyle = .short
let date = dateFormatter.string(from: peek.timestamp)
peekTimeLabel.text = "\(date)"
```

Comment: If you trying to set label after app started you can set timer with swift Timer() and update it after 60 secounds

Comment: See [these search results](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bswift%5D+doesRelativeDateFormatting).